# Keydown on DIV to refer some Location

Tags: javascript, html, location-href

i know how to make div to refer a location when it is clicked

```
<div onclick="location.href='newurl.html';" tabindex="0"><a>Text</a></div>
```

But it work when only clicked by mouse, but if i want to navigate through keyboard and press "Enter key" or "Space key" it wont work..

So what i want is something like this

```
<div onkeydown="location.href='newurl.html';" tabindex="0"><a>Islam</a></div>
```

and i dont wanna write code somewhere else like js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just attach both listeners to the `div`, and in `onkeydown` check the pressed key:

```
<div
  onkeydown="if(event.which===32||event.which===13) location.href='newurl.html';"
  onclick="location.href='newurl.html';"
  tabindex="0"
>
    <a>Islam</a>
</div>
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx6e7/).

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what you want, but maybe your are looking for `event.keyCode`. It gives you a code of pressed key and you can easily check `Enter` and `Space`.

```
<div onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13||event.keyCode==32)location.href='newurl.html'; " onclick="location.href='newurl.html';" tabindex="0">Link</div>
```